# Règles d'utilisation de « leur » et « leurs »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord, déterminants, possessif

Quand doit-on utiliser *leurs* avec un *s* ?

Quelles sont les règles (et les exceptions s'il y en a) pour l'accorder au pluriel ?

Existe-t-il un « truc » facile à retenir pour bien l'accorder ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

La difficulté vient principalement de l'homonymie entre le pronom personnel *leur*, le pronom possessif *leur* et le déterminant¹ *leur*.

- Le pronom personnel *leur* ne s'accorde pas²
- Le déterminant et le pronom possessif *leur* s'accordent en nombre avec l'élément dont il est la tête³ dans le cas du déterminant, avec son objet (le possédé) dans le cas du pronom

En pratique :

- Si on peut remplacer *leur + X* pas *le/la/les X des Y*  c'est que c'est un déterminant (ou traditionnellement un adjectif possessif), il s'accorde en nombre avec ce qu'il détermine⁴.

  > C'est leur père → C'est **le** père **des** enfants

  *leur* détermine *père*, qui est singulier, on accorde au singulier *leur*.

  > Ce sont leurs pommes → Ce sont **les** pommes **des** enfants

  *leurs* détermine *pommes*, qui est pluriel, donc on accorde au pluriel *leurs*.
- Si on peut remplacer *leur* par *mien(ne)(s)*, c'est un pronom possessif, et il s'accorde en nombre avec son objet (le possédé)

  > Les leurs sont plus jolies → Les **miennes** sont plus jolies

  *Leurs* remplace plusieurs objets donc on accorde au pluriel

  On peut aussi là encore remplacer *leur* par *le/la/les X de Y*

  > Ce sont les leurs ! → Ce sont **les** flûtes **de** Fañch et Søren !

  Ici aussi *leurs* remplace plusieurs objets donc on accorde au pluriel.
- Sinon c'est un pronom personnel (précisément le datif pluriel de la troisième personne), il ne s'accorde pas⁴ et il remplace un [complément d'attribution](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_%28grammaire%29#Compl.C3.A9ment_d.27objet_second_ou_d.27attribution)

  > Donnez-**leur** le choix → Donnez le choix aux enfants.

---

<sup>1. Parfois dit *déterminant possessif*</sup>
<sup>2. Il est en fait déjà accordé, puisque c'est le pluriel de *lui*.</sup>
<sup>3. X', quand tu nous tiens…</sup>
<sup>4. Vous m'avez compris.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Il y a le cas toujours ambigu où l'on fait référence à plusieurs personnes possédant chacune un élément. Faut-il écrire *"Ils sont venus avec **leurs** voitures"* ou *"Ils sont venus avec **leur** voiture"* ?

D'après [l'Académie](https://web.archive.org/web/20121130221755/http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#45_strong-em-leur-chapeau-ou-leurs-chapeaux-em-strong), la littérature utilise les deux.

Answer (score 2):

Les adjectifs possessifs remplacent l'article et peuvent changer de forme en fonction du possesseur et l'objet possédé ([page wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectif_possessif)).

On utilise *leur* ou *leurs* quand le possesseur est de la 3ème personne du pluriel (ils ou elles).

- Lorsque l'objet possédé est au *singulier*, on utilise **leur**. (ex: les enfants jouent avec **leur** ballon.)
- Lorsque l'objet possédé est au *pluriel*, on utilise **leurs**. (ex : les enfants jouent avec **leurs** jouets.)

Answer (score 1):

Sous *leur* et *leurs* se cachent en fait *trois* entités différentes :

- le pronom objet indirect (datif) de la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du pluriel, celui-ci est invariable :

  > Ils insistaient. Je *leur* ai dit de partir.
- le déterminant possessif de la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du pluriel, qui prend un *s* lorsque le possédé est pluriel.

  > *Leur* père a eu vite fait de réparer *leurs* vélos.
- un pronom possessif qui s'accorde de la même façon :

  > Cette idée, ce n'est pas la *leur*. Les *leurs* sont rarement aussi brillantes.

Answer (score 1):

Je pensais à citer [ce fil](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=64548&p=2227919#post2227919) instructif de la part de Wordreference.com par l'utilisateur  pheelineerie
:

> **Adjectif possessif:**
>   Their dog = leur chien
>   Their dogs = leurs chiens
>
> **Pronoun possessif:**
>   It's theirs - c'est le leur
>   They're theirs - ce sont les leurs
>
> **Complément d'objet indirect:**
>   He gave her a dog: Il lui a donné un chien
>   He gave them a dog = Il leur a donné un chien

Voici un autre fil que je dois parcourir en premier: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=182055&page=4